# How can I configure Wireguard running in a docker container on a VPS to allow communication between its' connected clients?

Tags: linux, docker, nat, wireguard

I have a VPS running WireGuard as a server in a docker container, where I've given it the devices I intend on adding as peers.

I have a home server running WireGuard as a client in a docker container using the host network mode. IP Forwarding is enabled on each of these servers.

When I connect with my laptop to the WireGuard host on the VPS, I'm unable to access my home server.

Am I approaching this wrong, or is there a simpler/better way to try to achieve this?
One of the reasons I'm wanting to configure this in this way is so that I can set up a reverse proxy to one of the services running on the home server over the tunnel.